# When installing Tailwind CSS in Vue 3, do I need a postcss.config.js file?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css

I'm struggling to install Tailwind CSS 2.2.10 in a Vue 3 project **without Vite** (so the *"[Install Tailwind CSS with Vue 3 and Vite](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vue-3-vite)"* instructions **do not apply**)

Within the installation documentation, the "[Add Tailwind as a PostCSS plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#add-tailwind-as-a-post-css-plugin)" section reads:

> Add tailwindcss and autoprefixer to your PostCSS configuration. Most
> of the time this is a postcss.config.js file at the root of your
> project, **but it could also be a** .postcssrc file, or **postcss key in
> your package.json file**.

Is `"postcss": "^8.3.6",` in my package.json file the "postcss key" mentioned in the docs (see bold above), or do I need a postcss.config.js file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `"postcss": "^8.3.6"` in the package.json file is **not** the "postcss key" mentioned in the docs - it's the version specifier for the `postcss` dependency.

The "**postcss key in your package.json file**" refers to a `postcss` root property in the JSON:

```json
// package.json
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    /*...*/
  }, 
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "tailwindcss": {},
      "autoprefixer": {},
    }
  }
}
```

If you prefer not to store the config in `package.json`, you could use one of the other possible locations where the PostCSS config is read, including `postcss.config.js`. However, you don't need more than one PostCSS config file (e.g., `postcss.config.js` in addition to the `postcss` key in `package.json`).

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in order to create `postcss.config.js`:

```
npx tailwindcss init -p
```